# Exclude lines when uploading Excel to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a website that uploads the content of an Excel to MYSQL database. The problem is that I have a gap between lines that I want to ignore.

This is as example....

[image: Gap thar stars on line 307 and ends in 312]

This is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

$connect = mysqli_connect("","","", "");

$ficheiro = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($ficheiro['tmp_name']);

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){

    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for($row=34; $row<=306; $row++) //I have this for but I want to exclude those lines

    {
        $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue();
        $nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
        $MarcaExploracao = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
        $NumeroChip = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue()));
        $Number = ltrim($NumeroChip,'0');
        $MarcaAuricular = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getValue());
        $Data_Nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row)->getValue());
        $ano = substr($Data_Nascimento,0,6);
        $anoValido = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $ano);
        $idade = date('Y')-$anoValido;
        //$unixDate = ($Data_Nascimento - 25569) * 86400;
        //$Data_Nascimento = gmdate("Y-m-d", $unixDate);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO animal(NIF,MarcaExploracao,numerochip,MarcaAuricular,Data_Nascimento,id_utilizador,ano,idade) VALUES(".$nif.", '".$MarcaExploracao."', '".$Number."', '".$MarcaAuricular."', '".$Data_Nascimento."',{$_SESSION['id_utilizador']},'".$anoValido."','".$idade."')";
        mysqli_query($connect,$sql);


    }
}
?>
    <script>
    alert("Excel adicionado");
    self.location="InserirOvelhas.php";
    </script>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a test for one (or more) of the columns that must be set in your loop and use `continue;` to make the script jump to the next index in the for loop

```
<?php
session_start();
include("excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

$connect = mysqli_connect("","","", "");

$ficheiro = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($ficheiro['tmp_name']);

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){

    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for($row=34; $row<=332; $row++) {
        //I have this for but I want to exclude those lines
        // looks like a line that should not exist
        //$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue();

        // ignore rows
        if ( $row > 306 && $row < 312) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue() == '' ) {
            continue;   // go to next for
        }


        $nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
        $MarcaExploracao = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
        $NumeroChip = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue()));
        $Number = ltrim($NumeroChip,'0');
        $MarcaAuricular = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$row)->getValue());
        $Data_Nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$row)->getValue());
        $ano = substr($Data_Nascimento,0,6);
        $anoValido = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $ano);
        $idade = date('Y')-$anoValido;
        //$unixDate = ($Data_Nascimento - 25569) * 86400;
        //$Data_Nascimento = gmdate("Y-m-d", $unixDate);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO animal(NIF,MarcaExploracao,numerochip,MarcaAuricular,Data_Nascimento,id_utilizador,ano,idade) VALUES(".$nif.", '".$MarcaExploracao."', '".$Number."', '".$MarcaAuricular."', '".$Data_Nascimento."',{$_SESSION['id_utilizador']},'".$anoValido."','".$idade."')";
        mysqli_query($connect,$sql);


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to go 34 to 306 and then 313 to 332 how I can put that in this code?   if ( $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue() == '' ) {
            continue;   // go to next for
        }

Comment: Ok I added another If so it ignores the rows you dont want to process, and changed the for loop terminator value